# Вход в phpmyadmin на OpenServer

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, openserver

Пытаюсь войти на phpmyadmin но у меня ошибка

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Создал нового пользователя, но войти не могу, где можно изменить пароль?

Comment: Вы после создания выдали все нужные права пользователю? Попробуйте через клиент командной строки mysql

Comment: @китайецИзКитая подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Смотрите совет в Ответе. Пользователь root и без пароля это по умолчанию учётка mysql

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, только я не создавал нового пользователя, я и через root не могу зайти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `root` пользователя ввести - войдете вообще ко всем базам и там уже что сделаете с нужной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, только я не создавал нового пользователя, я и через root не могу зайти